# Background position changing on hover

Tags: css, background, hover, position, background-position

I've been having a CSS problem. I have a div which includes a div for an image, a div containing links and a div containing a description, named as sidebar, sbpic, lks and desc, respectively.

For the image, this is the code I have currently:

```
#sbpic {
background-image:url('{image:Sidebar1}');
background-attachment:fixed;
background-repeat:repeat;
background-position:0px 50px;
position:fixed;
width:230px;
height:130px;
margin:10px 0px 0px -25px;
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease-out;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease-out;
transition: all 1s ease-out;  
}

#sidebar:hover #sbpic {
margin-top:305px;
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease-out;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease-out;
transition: all 1s ease-out;  
}
```

It works fine on the preview, as you can see [here](http://oi34.tinypic.com/33ykrjn.jpg)

But when I open up my site, this is the result [here](http://i36.tinypic.com/14v4nrk.jpg)

I've tried using #sbpic:hover and changing the background position there, and I've also tried changing the background position on #sidebar:hover #sbpic. The first would only work if I hovered over the picture, and the latter would make the picture be off by 50px when it reached the bottom.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you please create a http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: FYI you don't need to repeat the transition info in the hover, they are inherited

Comment: It seems to work fine on jsfiddle, as well...here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/Usvc3/

Comment: So, what's the problem?

Comment: On my live preview, it still doesn't work well...here: http://noitsnotitsnotokay.tumblr.com/ I'm not sure what it is?

Comment: Works perfectly on Win7 FF 20.